# R the change of rnorm is rlnorm

Tags: r, plot

I have my code that present my histogram correctly for rnorm:

```
pdf("plot1.pdf")
V_max=10
V_min=0
H=1
n=1

x_lim_min=-1
x_lim_max=13


par(mfrow=c(length(C)+1,1), mar = c(2,0,2,0),oma = c(1,5,0,0))



base_plot_fun <- function(x, x1, y, y1) {
  mean_x <- mean(x)
  mean_x1 <- mean(x1)
  
  # initialize the plot
  plot(
    0,
    0,
    ylim = range(c(y$counts, y1$counts)),
    xlim = range(c(y$breaks, y1$breaks)),
    xlab = "x",
    ylab = "counts",
    type = "n"
    
  )
  
  
  corners <- par('usr') # get the corners of the plots
  
  x_left <- corners[1]
  x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95) # at 95 percentile, change as needed
  
  x1_left <- x_right
  x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05) # at 5th percentile, change if needed
  
  rect(
    xleft = x_left,
    xright = x_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'lightblue',
    density = 100
  )
  rect(
    xleft = x1_left,
    xright = x1_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'pink',
    density = 100
  )
  
  plot(y, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
  plot(y1, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max)) 
  
  abline(v=x_right,col='steelblue',lwd=3)
  abline(v=x1_right,col='firebrick',lwd=3)
  abline(v=mean_x,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
  abline(v=mean_x1,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
  
}
x <- rnorm(100,V_min,1)
x1 <- rnorm(100,V_max,1)
y <- hist(x,plot=FALSE,breaks = 20)
y1 <- hist(x1, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)

base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)


dev.off()
```

I want to achieve a similar graph but for rlnorm

```
x <- rlnorm(100, meanlog = V_min, sdlog = 1)
 x1 <- rlnorm(100, meanlog = V_max, sdlog = 1)
```

to what values do I have to change V_min , V_max (these can be changed) to achieve a graph with similar histograms and the distance between them as in plot1. I don't know how to do it so I'm asking for help.

Comment: Any tips to my problem please?

Comment: Again, I am asking for help, this is an important question for me.

Comment: please help me with setting the V_max and V_min values so that the new plot looks like the one from plot1